# Android app with database constantly "starting/waiting for a blocking gc alloc"

Tags: android, sqlite

I've looked through specifically the addButtonClicked() method and the DBHandler itself. I can't figure out why the program basically gets stuck in an infinite loop when I try to add something to the database. Every time I run it and try to add something to the database it just freezes and gives this message over and over and over.

Error:

```
10-27 20:34:50.303 2849-2849/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-27 20:34:50.303 2849-2849/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
10-27 20:34:50.312 2849-2849/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
10-27 20:34:50.408 2849-2849/com.example.test.assignment W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.test.assignment-2/lib/x86
10-27 20:34:50.966 2849-2860/com.example.test.assignment W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.223ms
10-27 20:34:51.033 2849-2860/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 423(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 418(7MB) LOS objects, 38% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 6.686ms total 54.772ms
10-27 20:34:51.577 2849-2860/com.example.test.assignment W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.097ms
10-27 20:34:51.816 2849-2860/com.example.test.assignment I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 11.994ms for cause Background
10-27 20:34:52.017 2849-2860/com.example.test.assignment W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.393ms
10-27 20:34:52.023 2849-2860/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 845(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 843(41MB) LOS objects, 76% free, 1233KB/5MB, paused 10.623ms total 31.789ms
10-27 20:34:52.132 2849-2860/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 752(27KB) AllocSpace objects, 747(37MB) LOS objects, 15% free, 21MB/25MB, paused 20.980ms total 40.058ms
10-27 20:34:53.000 2849-2849/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
10-27 20:34:53.001 2849-2849/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-27 20:34:53.123 2849-2849/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
10-27 20:34:53.126 2849-2849/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
10-27 20:34:53.195 2849-2849/com.example.test.assignment I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
10-27 20:34:53.205 2849-2849/com.example.test.assignment I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 10.178ms for cause Alloc
```

It just keeps running that over and over and the printSelectedDatabase() is never ran because it doesn't show in the text view.

Main Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText dataInput;
    TextView showText;
    DBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dataInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dataInput);
        showText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showText);
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        printSelectedDatabase();
    }

    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Animals animal = new Animals(dataInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addAnimal(animal);
        printSelectedDatabase();
    }

    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        String string = dataInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteAnimal(string);
        printSelectedDatabase();
    }

    public void printSelectedDatabase(){
        String string = dbHandler.printDatabase();
        showText.setText(string);
        dataInput.setText("");
    }
}
```

Setter/Getters:

```
public class Animals {

    private int _id;
    private String _animalName;

    public Animals(){

    }

    public Animals(String animalName) {
        this._animalName = animalName;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_animalname(String _animalName) {
        this._animalName = _animalName;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_animalName() {
        return _animalName;
    }
}
```

DBHandler:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "animals.db";
    public static final String TABLE_ANIMALS = "animals";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ANIMALS = "animalName";

    public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ANIMALS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_ANIMALS + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ANIMALS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add Animal
    public void addAnimal(Animals animal){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ANIMALS, animal.get_animalName());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_ANIMALS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    //Delete Animal
    public  void deleteAnimal(String animalName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ANIMALS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ANIMALS + "=\"" + animalName + "\";");
    }

    //Print Animals
    public String printDatabase(){
        String string = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ANIMALS + " WHERE 1";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("animalName"))!=null){
                string += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("animalName"));
                string += "\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return string;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out in case anyone happens to run into this particular error. In my DBHandler I was missing a go to next line within the while statement.

Original:

```
 while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("animalName"))!=null){
                    string += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("animalName"));
                    string += "\n";
                }
            }
```

Should be:

```
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("animalName"))!=null){
                string += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("animalName"));
                string += "\n";
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to add on your answer. Instead of:

```
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
   // do stuff with cursor
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

your code would be more concise with:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // do stuff with cursor
}
```

When you do a query, the Cursor object is positioned BEFORE the first entry. The call to `cursor.moveToNext()` moves to the next position AND returns `true` if there is actually a record to move to and `false` otherwise.

Also, avoid calling `cursor.getColumnIndex("columnName")` from within a loop. You are better off caching the column index in an int variable and referring to that variable inside the loop.

```
int animalNameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("animalName");
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       if(cursor.getString(animalNameColumn)!=null){
            string += cursor.getString(animalNameColumn);
            string += "\n";
        }
}
```